# Проблема с вставкой на сайт yandex share кода. Между картинками возникают точки

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Внедрил на сайт следующий код:

```
<div class="share">
 <div class="title">Поделиться:</div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//yastatic.net/share2/share.js" async="async" charset="utf-8"></script>
 <div class="ya-share2" data-services="vkontakte,facebook,twitter,viber,whatsapp,odnoklassniki,moimir,telegram,skype"></div>
</div>
```

В результате получил следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что необходимо исправить или добавить, чтобы этих фиолетовых точек не было?

Comment: В консоль браузера загляните, может ошибки какие есть.

Comment: Скорей всего точки это оформление тега **ul**. Добавьте для него в файле css строку `list-style: none;`

Comment: Большое спасибо! Сейчас буду смотреть

Comment: Попробовал, не сработало.

Answer (score 0):

Видимо у вас какой-то CSS возвращает точки спискам, потому что если вставить ваш код в пустую страницу, то будет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы это исправить надо, надо добавить в CSS

```
.ya-share2__list {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Сейчас буду смотреть.

Comment: Попробовал, но не сработало. А есть возможность прописать в скрипте самого блока "поделиться" правило (что это не список)?

Comment: Можно тому тому CSS'у, что я написал ранее, поставить `!important`